# Load testing a sign-in page with 100 concurrent users

Tags: angularjs, load-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, blazemeter

I have a situation where a sign in button actually fires a call to following actions:

1. calling a auth service and gets a token
2. calls service A with token
3. calls service B with token
4. calls service C with token

Please note again all these actions are made(serially) on clicking the single sign-in button

I am actually trying to tune the system by applying some metrics monitoring. The problem is I want to load test the sign in process with 100 concurrent users for confirming that tuning works. I actually tried using jmeter with concurrency thread groups after recording the process above in jmeter script by means of blazemeter chrome plugin, but i found a difficulty there when i ran the test the threads are just keep hiting the urls involved in sign-in in arbitrary manner. i dont want that. what i want is: i have 100 * 4 threads and the group of these 4 threads should run concurrently but in each group the thread should run serially and the token in each group should be the one recieved from the auth call. Is it possible to attain such thing ?

Answer (score 0):

Each JMeter thread (virtual user) is executing [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) upside down (or according to the [Logic Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers)) so if you don't need to run requests 2-4 in parallel you basically don't have to do anything.

If you're confused by the order of the requests you can add [${__threadNum} function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) as the prefix (or postfix) and ensure that each virtual user is executing requests as they appear in the Thread Group

[image]

If you need to get the token and then execute requests 2-4 at the same time - put them under the [Parallel Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter/)